# c++ how to add values to vector (or array) by function?

Tags: c++, vector, reference, primes

I'll want to make a the Sieve of Eratosthenes, which I've made in the prime function, but the problem is that I'll want to use a vector, or something like it to store the value to later be use on the code, the rest is a binary search, but I don't know how to use the reference of the vector, I've done it on java, but the reference there is easy.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int *primes (int size)
{
    int* primArray = new int(size);
    int notPrime[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        notPrime[i]=0;
    int cont = 0;
    for(int i = 2; i < size; i++)
    {
        if(notPrime[i] == 0)
        {
            primArray[cont] = i;
            cont++;
            int sum = i;
            for(int j = 1; sum < size; j++)
            {
                notPrime[sum] = 1;
                sum = j*i;
            }
        }
    }
    return primArray;
}
```

the problem up here

```
int search(int input, vector<int> array)
{
    int min = 0;
    int max = array.size() - 1;
    int guess = (min + max)/2;
    int output = -1;
    while (true)
    {
        if (array[guess] == input)
        {
            output = guess;
            break;
        }
        if (min > max)
        {
            output = -1;
            break;
        }
        if (array[guess] < input)
            min = guess + 1;
        else
            max = guess - 1;
        guess = (min + max)/2;
    }
    return output;
}

int main()
{
    scanf("%d", &input);
    //int* array = primes(200);
    /*for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
    {
        printf("%d, ", array[i]);
    }*/
    int numbers[] = {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101, 103, 107, 109, 113, 127, 131, 137, 139, 149, 151, 157, 163, 167, 173, 179, 181, 191, 193, 197, 199};
    vector<int> primeArray (numbers, numbers + sizeof(numbers) / sizeof(*numbers));
    for (int i = 0; i < primeArray.size(); i++)
    {
        printf("%d, ", primeArray[i]);
    }
    cout<< "\n";
    printf("%d", search(input, primeArray));
}
```

Comment: What problem are you seeing?

Answer (score 0):

- The line `int* primArray = new int(size);` is bad because it allocates only 1 element initialized to `size` and it doesn't mean allocating `size` elements.
  To allocate `size` elements, use `int* primArray = new int[size];`
- References can be declared using `&`
  like this: `int search(int input, vector<int>& array)`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, a bit of advice:

do not mix C++ and C style code. if you want to use `printf()` and `scanf()` use C. if you want `std::vector` and `std::cout` then use C++. 
if you use C feel free to use arrays but in C++ you are **almost never** encouraged to be using arrays when you have access to `std::vector`

Mixing these programming styles is only going to complicate things for you down the line.

now as for your code:

You are not experiencing problems due to a lack of passing by reference.

Every time you do `search(input, primeArray)` you are passing `primeArray` by value. that means the copy constructor of `std::vector<int>` is called and a fresh copy of your vector is created before being passed to the search function. However this is not an issue because **you are not modifying** `primearray` **inside your search function**

If you want to pass in by reference you can change the signature of `search` to take a reference like this: `int search(int input, vector<int>& array)`

Actual problems:

In your `primes` function you have  `int* primArray = new int(size);` and I suspect this line is not doing what you want.

`new int (size);` will allocate 1 `int` on the heap and initialize that value to whatever the value of `size` is.

If you want to allocate a block of memory for `size` integers you need `int * primArray = new int[size];`

More issues:

In the first line of your `main` function you have `scanf("%d", &input);` but `input` has not been initialized anywhere.

I know you commented out the section in your `main` where you call `int* primes()` but you have to remember that if you allocate dynamic memory anywhere, you MUST release that memory later. In your case because your program ends at the end of `main`, your dynamic memory will be released implicitly, but it is always good practice to release the memory yourself.

Failure to due so will introduce *memory leaks* in your program.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll take your advice on not mixing languages, and well, I'd have said that the program work, but I've wanted to make better using vectors and not the array, I have made the program print the prime numbers and them copy them into the array manually and well that's not correct, but now I'll use the vector thanks